# How to keep the Bottom Navigation Bar persistent in certain screen of my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have 2 different `BottomNavigationBar's` defined within my app. One for authenticated users and another for unauthenticated users.

Listed below are the variables relevant to the `BottomNavigationBar`:

```
  int selectedIndex = 0;

  final authenticatedScreens = [
    HomePage(),
    SearchPage(),
    CoursesPage(),
    ProfilePage(),
  ];

  final unAuthenticatedScreens = [
    HomePage(),
    SearchPage(),
    CoursesPage(),
    SignIn(),
  ];
```

Listed below is the code present within the `build` method:

```
.
.
.
return user == null
                ? Container(
                    child: Scaffold(
                      bottomNavigationBar: buildUnAuthenticatedBottomNavigationBar(context),
                      body: SafeArea(child: unAuthenticatedScreens[selectedIndex]),
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    child: Scaffold(
                      bottomNavigationBar: buildAuthenticatedBottomNavigationBar(context),
                      body: SafeArea(child: authenticatedScreens[selectedIndex]),
                    ),
                  );
.
.
.
```

Listed below is the code for authenticated and unauthenticated `BottomNavigationBar's`:

```
  BottomNavigationBar buildAuthenticatedBottomNavigationBar(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: selectedIndex,
      onTap: (index) => setState(() => selectedIndex = index),
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 8.sp,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
      ),
      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 8.sp,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color!.withOpacity(0.4),
      ),
      showSelectedLabels: true,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
      unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color!.withOpacity(0.4),
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: "Home",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.home,
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: "Search",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: "Courses",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.auto_stories_outlined,
          ),
          activeIcon: Icon(
            Icons.auto_stories,
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: "Account",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.person,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  BottomNavigationBar buildUnAuthenticatedBottomNavigationBar(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: selectedIndex,
      onTap: (index) => setState(() => selectedIndex = index),
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 8.sp,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
      ),
      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 8.sp,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
        color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color!.withOpacity(0.4),
      ),
      showSelectedLabels: true,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
      unselectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color!.withOpacity(0.4),
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: "Home",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.home,
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: "Search",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: "Courses",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.auto_stories_outlined,
          ),
          activeIcon: Icon(
            Icons.auto_stories,
          ),
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          label: "Account",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.person,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

When I navigate to another screen from any of the 4 screens which are part of the `BottomNavigationBar`. The `BottomNavigationBar` disappears, I don't want the `BottomNavigationBar` to disappear. I want the `BottomNavigationBar` to remain persistent for certain screens and disappear for certain screens.

I did explore few solutions but didn't work out for me. I wouldn't like to make use of the `Cupertino` widgets.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

With using this package [Presistant_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar).so you can use bottomnavbar on every screen or you can do the above method

```
    PersistentTabController _controller =PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 1);
    
    //Screens for each nav items.
      List<Widget> _NavScreens() {
        return [
         
         OfferScreen(),
         
         HelpScreen(),
         HomeScreen(),    
         ProfileScreen(),
         CartViewScreen(),
          
        ];
      }
    
    
      List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() {
        return [
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
           icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            title: ("Home"),
            activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeBlue,
            inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            title: ("OFFERS"),
            activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeGreen,
            inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin),
            title: ("Help"),
            activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemRed,
            inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.local_activity),
            title: ("ProfileScreen"),
            activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemIndigo,
            inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
          ),
     PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shop_cart),
            title: ("Cart"),
            activeColor: CupertinoColors.systemIndigo,
            inactiveColor: CupertinoColors.systemGrey,
          ),
    
        ];
      }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: PersistentTabView(
            controller: _controller,
            screens: _NavScreens(),
            items: _navBarsItems(),
            confineInSafeArea: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true,
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
            hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
            decoration: NavBarDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            popAllScreensOnTapOfSelectedTab: true,
            navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style9,
          ),
        );
    }
```

Also you can use navigation bottombar in certain screen by using navigator-functions instead of flutter navigator.push(); use following `pushNewScreen`
for more details checkout [persistent_bottom_nav_bar#navigator-functions](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar#navigator-functions)

```
pushNewScreen(
        context,
        screen: MainScreen(),
        withNavBar: false, // OPTIONAL VALUE. True by default.
        pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Abhijith I guess this is based on the `Cupertino` widget. I did explore it. I'm not looking for a `Cupertino` based solution.

Comment: The problem with default material bottom navigation it doesn't recommend to use it on other pages, if you need you could have use custom style in the Presistant_bottom_nav_bar package. checkout this components for do and don'ts ,https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation @xpetta

Answer (score -1):

Yes I agree there are some package out there but doesn't provide full control  over it
What you can do is Use **Navigator** and all your taps and you need to manage s separate navigation stack for all taps.

Here is a great article by **Andrea Bizzotto**

https://medium.com/coding-with-flutter/flutter-case-study-multiple-navigators-with-bottomnavigationbar-90eb6caa6dbf

Comment: @xpetta this is the option you can have full control over it.
Can you tell me what is issue you are facing with this option?
And Why did down vote the question you asked for help I provide you with proper answer

Comment: I did try implementing it, but it didn't work for me. Maybe I did it wrong. If you can provide me the solution that should be really helpful. I'm still a newbie to Flutter.